# Manejar tiempo de respuesta con Curl en php

Tags: php

Lo que necesito hacer es crear una respuesta en caso de que trascuran 60 segundos y la api no responda

```
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $bodyAPI);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
            $responseAPI = curl_exec($ch);
            $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar esto

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 90);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
...
curl_exec($ch);
if ($error_number = curl_errno($ch)) {
    if (in_array($error_number, [CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT, CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEOUTED])) {
        echo("error en tiempo");
    }
}
curl_close($ch);
```